# GIT: Manually invoke 3-way-mergetool on a file on 2 branches

Tags: git

I'm on branch C on which I would like to inspect and (partially) integrate the differences between branch A and B of file.c.

Is there are way to manually have git invoke the (3-way)-merge-tool on one file when not being in a merge-situation?

```
file.c:A -> file.c:C <- file.c:B
```

Comment: See [git-merge-file](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-file.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `merge-file` - I wasn't aware of it, however it isn't really doing what I want at all. Lionel P.'s script is doing exactly what I want. I'm looking for a more direct way of doing it.

Comment: Probably should have said "see also" rather than "see".  Git doesn't have its own editor built in.  It does have `git mergetool` which can run various third-party merge-tools for you, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't found any direct ways on Git to do that, but here is an answer that makes the job :)

Use a Bash script like

```
#!/bin/bash

LEFTREV=$1
RIGHTREV=$2
FILENAME=$3

LEFTFNAME=$FILENAME.left
RIGHTFNAME=$FILENAME.right

git show $LEFTREV:$FILENAME > $LEFTFNAME
git show $RIGHTREV:$FILENAME > $RIGHTFNAME

meld $LEFTFNAME $FILENAME $RIGHTFNAME
```

Usage : git3way A B file.c
where A and B are your two branches.